# Create link or change python-mysql socket location

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, unix-socket

While testing SQLalchemy in Python I came over a similar problem to what I earlier also had experienced. This time, however, I could not easily add the mysql-socket path to the MySQLdb connection method.

On my mac the mySQL socket location is at: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

Unless mentioned the path above explicitly the mysql-python library looks to /tmp/mysqld.sock

This results in sqlachemy throwing:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL    server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)") None None
```

Before I have solved this problem by adding the unix_socket argument to the connection method

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (unix_socket = '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock',host = "localhost", user = "username", passwd= "password", db="database")
```

What I would like to find out, is how I can make permanent changes to the MySQLdb library settings, or to the file where these settings are stored (if anywhere) to not always have to add in the extra argument.

Comment: yes, it solves the problem with connecting. Thank you very much for the link. It would also be good to find a way of solving problem with mysql-python using another socket than what is the actual on the computer, so if you know a way of changing the setting that would be splendid.

Comment: I believe the default socket location is set up at compilation time (in the mysql client libraries).